# How to Show Browser-Saved Passwords in a dijit.form.TextBox Input

Tags: passwords, dojo

I am using a dijit.form.TextBox for a login form but cannot make browser-saved passwords appear in it like they would in a standard HTML input field.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the problem you are running into is that the template of `dijit.form.TextBox` has `autocomplete="off"` hard-coded into the input field.

There seem to be some reasons behind this:  http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/9562

If you really wanted, you could easily override the template to make this driven by a widget attribute instead, and I've done so in the past.  However, if I recall correctly, one browser or the other still won't "just work", possibly because the field gets inserted into the document dynamically and not as part of the initial page.  Bottom line: your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be well-documented, but look at the [example](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.5.0/dojo-release-1.5.0/dijit/tests/form/test_validate.html) in the tests directory.  Simply use the normal input attributes for password obfuscation.  Is that what you're talking about?

```
<input id="q23" type="password" name="password" class="medium"
    dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox">
```